# Is aws-sdk installed inbuilt in the AWS Lambda running environment?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I want to know which libraries are already installed in the environment when we use the AWS Lambda function. I am using node.js.

On the other hand, is there a way to call Cognito login/signup methods in Lambda without using the aws-amplify library because it is too heavy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the standard libraries as well as the AWS-SDK is preinstalled.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html

You can call cognito methods without using amplify. You can use the javascript AWS SDK.

Comment: One note: the pre-installed NodeJS AWS SDK is v2 not the more recent v3.